# using plain javascript with react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm hacking away at the react starter kit, and I came into a problem. I need javascript to get the query string from the url and display it in the document. I tried the following, but I get a location not defined. How can I do this in reacts and javascript?

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
      results = regex.exec(location.search);
  return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

@withStyles(styles)
class PlayerPage extends Component {
  render() {
    const title = 'Player';
    var player = getParameterByName('player');
    return (
      <div className="PlayerPage">
        <div className="PlayerPage-container">
          <h1>{title}</h1>
          <p>{player}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is client-side right? Have you checked if `window` is defined? Is the error specifically saying `location` is undefined, or is it saying "cannot read property location of undefined"? Sounds like either a scope issue, or this is server-side JS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when your code runs in the server, location will not be defined because the node.js environment does not provide an implementation of location.

You may want to ensure that this component only renders on the client, or extract the route information from express request in server, rather than relying only on location.